# Creating Cookies while rendering JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

I have what I feel should be a simple question that I've been unable to solve. I'm trying to set a cookie while rendering json data in a Rails 4 app.

```
def index
   request.cookies[:hi] = 'hello'
   render json: User.all
end
```

I've been trying to use ActionDispatch::Cookies, setting key/values in a cookies variable and a variety of other methods I've seen while Googleing, but nothing seems to work. Any suggestions? Is this not possible rendering json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    def index
       cookies[:hi] = "hello" 
       render json: User.all
    end

# Set a cookie that expires in 1 hour
cookies[:login] = { :value => "XJ12", :expires => Time.now + 3600}
# delete cookie
cookies.delete :login




All the option symbols for setting cookies are:

value - the cookie.s value or list of values (as an array).
path - the path for which this cookie applies. Defaults to the root of the application.
domain - the domain for which this cookie applies.
expires - the time at which this cookie expires, as a +Time+ object.
secure - whether this cookie is a secure cookie or not (default to false). Secure cookies are only transmitted to HTTPS servers.
```

this is correct way...

Comment: I've corrected my code to match yours, and restarted my app, but nothing is appearing.

Comment: great... :) @user2684405

Comment: @Milind
No way to set HttpOnly ?

Comment: setting cookies in json is as simple as setting key values...Thats it.